# How to configure iSCSI redirection on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, file-server, iscsi

[rfc 7143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7143.txt) defines the iSCSI redirection function. I don't have a Windows Server 2012 instance at hand. Is it possible to configure this feature on Windows Server 2012?

> Redirection - indicates that the initiator must take further action to
>   complete the request. This is usually due to the target moving to a
>   different address. All of the redirection Status-Class responses MUST
>   return one or more text key parameters of the type "TargetAddress",
>   which indicates the target’s new address.

Comment: It seems that there is no iSCSI Redirection functionality in Windows Server indeed. On the other hand, it will be possible to implement Active-Active connections between server nodes. In addition it will also be possible to activate the MPIO Policy of preference which would be able to provide "redirection" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried so far, I think Windows Server 2012 has no such support for iSCSI redirection.

I found a [comparison](http://scst.sourceforge.net/comparison.html) of iSCSI frameworks on Linux. 3 of them cliams to support iSCSI supports. I tried STGT and IET. I didn't find how to with STGT. But I did succeed with IET. Though IET can only work with Linux kernel version < 4.4.